# Business conversation by emails: should I say hello in each email?

Tags: politeness, email

I received this email from a company interested in my product.
I did not know them beforehand.

> Hello,
>   ...
>   John Doe

I replied like this:

> Hello John,
>   ...
>   Nicolas Raoul

And got this reply:

> Nicolas,
>   ...

What salutation should I use in my next reply?
Can I just use `John,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is broad and actually opinion based. Nevertheless, let me share what *I* practice.

We address people with *Hello* in emails quite commonly and this can go for **every** email you write or respond. However, if you are responding merely with a sentence or two, addressing person directly with their name (as *John* might have done in this case) is okay.

In another case, if it's the same conversation *(more like a chat)* having 2, 3 or more mails, *I* drop *Hello* and directly address the person with their name.

In this case, as I already said, you may choose any option - *Hello John,* or *John*. But if you want to sound a bit formal, go for *Hello John,*

Comment: I agree. You can't go wrong either way. When it comes to "Hello", no one will begrudge you for leaving it in, or leaving it out.